# What is the gradle's analogue for maven's <scope>test</scope>?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, unit-testing, gradle, h2

When I only wanna use h2 memory db to perform unit tests and in maven case use such definition:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

I don't need h2 when the application is working

What is the gradle's analogue for this purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

H2 is likely only to be needed at runtime by your tests, i.e. you test classes won't compile against any H2 classes. In this case, you should use the `testRuntimeOnly` configuration:

```
dependencies {
    testRuntimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
}
```

For dependencies that your test classes need to compile against, you should use the `testImplementation` configuration instead.